# single network with two routers

Tags: router, subnet, dhcp

I want to set up a wireless router to connect wireless devices with the rest of the network. I'm no specialist, so I'm not sure how to ask this question.

I want the devices in the sub-network to be included in the main network, so that it would not make a difference wether you connect them to the wireless router or to the main network router. They should all be able to communicate as if they were all in one network. (have the same Irange and stuff like that)

I have seen a similar question with the same problem, but it only needs cable devices to work, so a switch is a really simple solution. However, I need this to work with wireless devices.

**What settings should I use?**

Im sorry for the bad explanation, but as I said I'm no specialist.

Comment: Please post the existing configuration of your wireless ap as well as what model it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many wireless routers allow you to configure them in bridge mode, where you connect the uplink of the wireless router to a switch port on your main router, and it broadcasts a wireless network (with whatever settings you like). Any traffic from clients connected to the wifi is then relayed back/forth onto the wired router as if they were connected directly. Perhaps that is what you'd like?